# Xcode not finding header file for other project

Tags: ios, xcode, soundcloud

I'm trying to incorporate the SoundCloudAPI into my project, and I've followed the steps here https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Setup.md

After completing all those steps, everything builds ok. But then in my AppDelegate file when I try to `#import "SCAPI.h`", I get a file not found error right away. I've followed all the instructions in the tutorial and modified my header search paths in the build settings but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas why this can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because to projects are in the same workspace doesn't mean they can find each-others files. Try dragging the 'SoundCloudAPI.xcodeproj' onto your main project (A green add icon should appear),drop it to link the two.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two separate projects? If so, drag all of the files into your primary project. That could be the problem. That way all your files are in the same area and should be accessible by each other.